# select more than one row

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

```
void BaseMySQL::QueryArray(char *InQuery,std::string outResult[])
{
    query_state = mysql_query(con, InQuery);
    if (query_state !=0) {
    printf("%s",mysql_error(con));
    }
     res = mysql_store_result(con);
     m_fields = (WORD)mysql_num_fields(res);
    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res))!= NULL) {
        for(int i = 0; i < m_fields; i++)
        {
            outResult[i]=row[i];
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result(res);
}
```

the way this function am using works so lets say i have like 1000 account and my query is

> "select id,name,password from account"

my function will just get me the 1st row like if am using  `std::string acc[20];//array`

so

```
id=acc[0];
name=acc[1];
password=acc[2];
```

but my question which i cant figure it out how i can select all the rows and use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
row = mysql_fetch_row(res);
while(row) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m_fields; i++)
    {
        outResult[i]=row[i];
    }
    row = mysql_fetch_row(res);
}
```

Change your function like this. Its working for me.